# Subscribe with Bind

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android, rx-kotlin

Hello friends to improve the code below; Is there a way to directly "bind" the "event.position" value without having to subscribe?
Or better?

```
var index: BehaviorRelay<Int> = BehaviorRelay.createDefault(0)

mainViewPager.pageScrollEvents().subscribe(
        { event ->
            index.accept(event.position)
        }
    )
```

I think I'm looking for something like the following (This code will not work, just an example);

```
mainViewPager.pageScrollEvents().position.bind(index)
```

Comment: Won't something like `mainViewPager.pageScrollEvents().map(PageScrollEvent::position).subscribe(index)` work? (Disclaimer: I know neither RxRelay nor RxBinding)

Comment: you are a legend, yes it works